# Google signin throws error 16 and 12501 on some devices

Tags: android, google-signin

A few days ago we replaced our firebase 'backend' with our own solution, therefore we also got rid of firebase auth. The only part of the login that changed is how we handle the received idToken.

Prior the auth worked without issues but after removing firebase some devices started throwing `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException` with error codes 16 and 12501. Although both codes can be the result of users canceling the login we confirmed that users who have this error are not doing so. We cannot reproduce the error because the login works on our test devices.

One additional observation is that some users who reported to be effected could log in several days later without any updates or google account changes.

Google related parts of the signin:

```
// GoogleSignIn setup
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.google_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
googleClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

// start the signin flow
startActivityForResult(googleClient.signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE)

// result handling in onActivityResult
if (requestCode == RC_GOOGLE) {
    val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
    try {
        val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        doAuth("google", account!!.idToken!!)
    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        loginFailed(e)
    }
}
```

OS Versions: various, Android 8 predominantly

GMS version: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1`